# Adding and deleting a row from SQL database using Ajax and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP snippet that generates a table and fills it, and adds a delete button at the end of each row.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$num=$row['id'];
echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['adress']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['phonenumber']."</td>";
echo "<td><form action='delete.php' method='post'><button type='submit' value=$num name='deleteId'>delete</button></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";   
}
```

The delete.php file is this one :

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="students";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$id = $_POST['deleteId'];

$sql="DELETE FROM students WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

I want to do this using Ajax asynchronously, ie. I don't want my page to refresh. Tried a million ways, yet it fails each time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your may want to read this: [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).  And could you perhaps add the ajax code that you have tired so that we can see where you have possibly gone wrong

Comment: We do not see any javascript here. What have you tried then?

Comment: The problem with your query is the quotes around the $id: it is an integer and does not need, or work with those quotes. If you do not want to get marked down for this question, show what javascript you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a form, you need to write your own JavaScript to handle the server call. Here's one way to do it. Make your PHP look something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$num=$row['id'];
echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['adress']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['phonenumber']."</td>";
echo "<td><button onclick="deleteStudent($num)">delete</button></td>";
echo "</tr>";   
}
```

And then have a JS function that looks something like this:

```
function deleteStudent(studentId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "delete.php",
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        deleteId: studentId
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
Firstly, assign a unique ID for each of the delete button.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $num = $row['id'];
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['adress']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['phonenumber']."</td>";
    echo "<td><button id='delete-" . $row['id'] . "'>delete</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
}
```

Then use jQuery:

```
$('button[id^="delete"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(6);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete.php",
      data: {deleteId: id}
    });
});
```